# Set background as wallpaper using AndroidManifest

Tags: android

Can I somehow set background image of layout the same as wallpaper but **only from `AndroidManifest`**? I know that I can make it programmatically using this code:

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);//Substitute with your layout
        rl.setBackground(wallpaperDrawable);
```

But I repeat it again, **I need to do this through `AndroidManifetst`**.
Thank you.

Comment: Why must it be `AndroidManifest`? Can't you do it in the style XML files?

Comment: You need to extend your activities from a base activity where you would get the root view and apply the wallpaper as your background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class and extend it from `AppCompatAcitvity` or 'Activity'. override its `oncreate` method as follows.

```
public class myWallpaperActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
        View r1 = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        r1.setBackground(wallpaperDrawable);
    }
}
```

Now extend all your activities from this class.

`public class MainActivity extends myWallpaperActivity`

If you need to improve it and load new wallpaper if it is changed and the acitvity is not destroyed you can override the `onResume` method instead of `onCreate` method as follows

```
public class myWallpaperActivity extends Activity{


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
        View r1 = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        r1.setBackground(wallpaperDrawable);
    }
}
```

**Note that if a live wallpaper is set on device you would get a black background**

Comment: Will this code work with Activity? Or it needs only AppCompatActivity?

Comment: if you are using Activity extend it from Activity instead of AppCompatActivity

Comment: @S.Drumble2  Did it Work for you? You may select this as the answer if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can override a style and import that style in your manifest file...

```
<style name="Background" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
       or 
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/attachment1</item>
</style>
```

now on manifest file

```
<application  android:theme="@style/Background"/>
```

Cheers.

Comment: The OP wants to get the current wallpaper. In your solution it would be static